# Drawing arrows next to edges on graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tkz-graph

I need to draw several graphs (the graph theory kind) with arrows drawn next to the edges. Here is a rough sketch of the kind of thing I mean:

[image]

I'm aware of `tkz-graph` and would like to use it if possible - I have looked through its [manual](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-graph/doc/tkz-graph-screen.pdf) (I don't understand French but I can understand the code examples) but I don't see anything like this.

Alternatively I'm happy to use just plain `tikz` to do it, but I don't know how to draw things parallel to the edges in this way. (I want to do it automatically, not position the arrows by hand.)

Is there a straightforward way to do it, either in `tkz-graph` or just in `tikz`?

Comment: The TikZ graph drawing stuff is documented in the TikZ manual in English. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @cfr it helps a little bit, but the manual is over 850 pages and doesn't deal with the `tikz-graph` package as far as I can tell, so a more specific solution would be helpful. I'm reasonably familiar with tikz, but don't know how to do this particular task.

Comment: So would an MWE showing what you're tried. And the entire manual is not devoted to graph drawing. It has a section with a relevant title and everything, even if you don't like indices.

Comment: @Nathaniel, than you have an old TikZ manual. Recent (v 3.0.1a) has 1161 pages. So I advise you to upgrade your TikZ package.

Comment: @cfr if I could post a mwe I would already know how to answer the question. All I have tried so far is to look up how to do it, and I have failed at that. Beyond that there is nothing else I can try besides asking here.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for noticing that, I was being lazy and googling for the manual instead of looking on my system. The latest version also does not mention `tikz-graph`, at least according to a simple text search for the package name.

Comment: There is no package `tikz-graph` in standard TeX distributions. There is the graph-drawing stuff which is part of TikZ. But what you are reading in French, I have no idea.

Comment: @cfr my mistake, it's called `tkz-graph`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That makes more sense. I didn't know `tkz` had that, but I know the docs are in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure TikZ solution with help of `mathtools˙package:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = A going right,
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, 
                                     inner sep=2pt, on chain}] 
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \node {};
%
\node (B-1) [below=of A-2] {A};
\node (B-2) [below=of A-4] {B};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={above, sloped}]
\draw[densely dotted, thick] 
                (A-1) -- (A-2)
                (A-2) -- node {$\xleftarrow{1}$}  (A-3)
                (A-3) -- (A-4)
                (A-4) -- node {$\xleftarrow{1}$} (A-5);
\draw[thick]    (B-1) -- node {$\xleftarrow{1}$} (A-2)
                (B-1) -- node {$\xrightarrow{1}$}(A-3)
%
                (B-2) -- node[below] {$\xleftarrow[1]{}$} (A-3)
                (B-2) -- node {$\xleftarrow{1}$} (A-4)
                ;
%
\draw[double]   (A-1) --  (B-1)  
                (A-5) -- node[below] {$\xleftarrow[2]{}$} (B-2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
An alternative solution with help of `pic`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = A going right,
pics/AB/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{code={
    \draw[solid,-{Straight Barb[length=1mm]},very thick]
        (-3mm,#1 2mm) -- node [#2,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=2pt] {#3} ++ (6mm,0mm);}
                            },
pics/BA/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{code={
    \draw[solid,{Straight Barb[length=1mm]}-,very thick]
        (-3mm,#1 2mm) -- node [#2,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=2pt] {#3} ++ (6mm,0mm);}
                            }
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, 
                                     inner sep=2pt, on chain}] 
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \node {};
%
\node (B-1) [below=of A-2] {A};
\node (B-2) [below=of A-4] {B};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[sloped]
\draw[densely dotted, thick] 
                (A-1) -- (A-2)
                (A-2) -- pic {BA=/above/1} (A-3)%node {$\xleftarrow{1}$}  (A-3)
                (A-3) -- (A-4)
                (A-4) -- pic {AB=/above/1} (A-5);
\draw[thick]    (B-1) -- pic {AB=/left/1} (A-2)
                (B-1) -- pic {AB=-/above left/1} (A-3)
%
                (A-3) -- pic {BA=-/below left/1} (B-2)
                (B-2) -- pic {AB=/left/1} (A-4);
%
\draw[double]   (A-1) --  (B-1)  
                (A-5) -- pic {BA=-/below right/2} (B-2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: in the first version of addendum I mess up the arrow directions. Now this is corrected.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, and I think I can modify it for my other graphs. But is there a way to prevent the numbers from being rotated like that?

Comment: @Nathaniel, in the first solution numbers are part of arrows, consequently they are always oriented with arrow. However, meantime I added another solution, where numbers are oriented as you like to have them.

Comment: I much prefer the look of the first version, with the Computer Modern arrows. However, rather than bug you about how to achieve the exact effect I want, I'll accept this answer and ask a separate question, so that I can understand how to do it myself.

Comment: The new question is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296216/positioning-of-nodes-relative-to-edges-in-tikz

Comment: Many apologies for the unaccept. It occurred to me that the author of `tkz-graph` is active on the site and might post an answer. If that doesn't happen, I'll accept this again.

Comment: It is ok. I only provide TikZ solution ... with tkz-graph I haven't enough experiences to make any suggestion of ti use.